# avoiding repetition

Tags: repetition

I know it's correct to say:

> "Talking of **news**, I have good **news**".

But being "news" an uncountable noun, I think that the sentence:

> "Talking of **news**, I have a good **one**"

is incorrect. So, if I want to avoid repeating it, what should I use instead?

Comment: Talking of good news, here's some: [talks].  Otherwise, you must repeat it: Talking of news, here's some good news: [talks].

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, repetition is bad, as you already pointed out.

However, used with care, repetition can be good, for adding some emphasis or artistic style.

In your example, by repeating "**news**" you actually add emphasis that not only you have **news**, but they are important / exciting **news**.

Alternatively, you can use "new information", but you are probably not going to be any better.